# How to toggle laravel trashed filter off temporarily?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, soft-delete

Say I've got an A, which has a B that has a C that has a D. I want to go from A to D, but any one (or all) of the objects might have been deleted. So I have to do this:

```
$d = $a->b()->withTrashed()->first()->c()->withTrashed()->first()->d()->withTrashed()->first()
```

Which is horrible. I would really rather do this:

```
turnOffTrashedFilter();
$d = $a->b->c->d;
```

Does laravel have such an ability?

Note that this is just an example - the situation that prompted this question is actually a lot more complicated, with various calls nested in other calls such that it's not practically possible to use withTrashed as above. I need to turn off the filter for the duration of the request, without having to modify huge swathes of code to incorporate two parallel paths.

Comment: do 2 relationship per item one with trashed and one without. and then you can use them as needed

Comment: You could create a model function so you only have to write this once

Comment: I'd argue that selecting `withTrashed` should be explicit every time so it's obvious what you're doing and to prevent issues when you forget to switch the trashed filter on in code. What @Indra suggests is a good middle-ground to get the best of both worlds

Comment: @Indra, this is a fine solution for the problem in my example, but it doesn't answer my question - I'm specifically asking about if there is a way to turn off filtering in general, which there might not be, but adding a bunch of new methods is a solution of last resort.

Comment: @apokryfos That is absolutely true in general, unfortunately the ball of mud I'm working with is written in such a way that explicitly calling out withTrashed to each call will actually make it *less* clear.

Comment: That being said I've checked the source code and it seems that the `SoftDeletingScope` is added on a per-model basis so it needs to be removed on a per-model basis as well, so basically there's no global kill-switch for it as far as I can tell. If the option to extend the `SoftDeletes` trait with your own and use that in all your models is a viable one then you might be able to whip something up that achieves this though.

Comment: @Benubird i know. I should have been more explicit in my comment. This is why I didn't add an answer. i'm glad you found the right solution. I saw your answer.

Answer (score 1):

### No built-in, but it can be done

There is no built in way to disable the automatic soft delete filtering. However, it is possible. The soft delete filter is a global scope, added to the boot method of the class. It can be removed like so:

```
    \Event::listen('eloquent.booted:*', function($name) {
    $name = substr($name, 17); // event name is "eloquent.booted: some/class"
    $class = new \ReflectionClass($name);
    $prop = $class->getProperty('globalScopes');
    $prop->setAccessible(true);
    $scopes = $prop->getValue();
    foreach ($scopes as $c => &$s) {
        unset($s['Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope']);
    }
    $prop->setValue($scopes);
});
```

This hooks into the booted event, which is fired immediately after the global scope gets added to the class. It then opens the (private static) attribute globalScopes, which is a list of the attached global scopes, and removes the soft deleting one. This will prevent the softdelete scope from being attached to any models, provided their static boot method is called *after* the event listener is added.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this you can use withTrashed() in your relations:

```
public function aTrashed()
{
    return $this->hasOne(A::class)->withTrashed();
}

public function bTrashed()
{
    return $this->hasMany(B::class)->withTrashed();
}

public function cTrashed()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(C:class)->withTrashed();
}

// Then use it
$d = $z->aTrashed->bTrashed->cTrashed;
```